# boost::bind - Getting write access to member variable? (Like boost::multi_index::member)

Tags: boost, boost-bind, boost-multi-index

Just out of curiosity, is there a way to get write access to member variables via `boost::bind`? I can get it via `boost::multi_index::member`, but just want to know other methods as well.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    string name;
    Test(const string &name)
        : name(name)
    { }
};

int main()
{
    Test test("Bob");
    boost::multi_index::member<Test, string, &Test::name> nameMember;
    string &ref = nameMember(test);
    cout << ref << "\n";
    // Write Access
    ref = "Tim";

    // Read-only Access
    boost::function<const string& (Test*)> nameGetter = boost::bind(&Test::name, _1);
    cout << nameGetter(&test) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Bob
Tim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
// Read-write Access
boost::function<string&(Test*)> nameSetter =
                                      boost::bind<std::string&>(&Test::name, _1);
nameSetter(&test) = "test";
cout << ref << "\n";
```